# What is equivalent HTML code for Spring's <form:errors/> tag?

Tags: html, spring

Im using Spring 3.2, Im dynamically adding input elements using jquery,  to my Spring form. I want to add the *errors* also associated with it. But I dont know the equivalent HTML code for `<form:errors />` tags. When you use the following Spring tag in JSP page

```
<form:text path="abc" />
```

it produces the following HTML while rendering

```
<input type="text" name="abc" />
```

What does it produce for the following Spring form errors tag while rendering as HTML?

```
<form:errors path="abc"/>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Errors are generated either a) with JavaScript, or b) on the server. There is no HTML-only `<form:errors />`.

Answer (score 0):

It depends how you use the errors tag.  With your specific example:

```
<form:errors path="abc"/>
```

I believe the resulting HTML will be:

```
<span id="abc.errors">abc is messed up for some reason</span>
```

Personally, I use the errors tag like this:

```
<form:errors path="*" cssClass="error"/>
```

And my HTML is:

```
<span id="*.errors" class="error">Title is required</span>
```

I hope that helps!